# Check if Variable is Empty - Angular 2

Tags: angular

How can one check if a variable is empty in Angular 2? I know that there are native ways such as

`if (myVar === null) {do stuff}`

but I am looking for something like Angular 1 had such as

`if (angular.isEmpty(variable)) { do stuff }`.

**Q** How do check if variable is empty using Angular 2?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Lets say we have a variable called x, as below:

```
var x;
```

following statement is valid,

```
x = 10;
x = "a";
x = 0;
x = undefined;
x = null;
```

1. Number:

```
x = 10;
if(x){
//True
}
```

and for `x = undefined` or `x = 0` (be careful here)

```
if(x){
 //False
}
```

2. String  `x = null` , `x = undefined` or `x = ""`

```
if(x){
  //False
}
```

3 Boolean `x = false` and `x = undefined`,

```
if(x){
  //False
}
```

By keeping above in mind we can easily check, whether variable is empty, null, 0 or undefined in Angular js. Angular js doest provide separate API to check variable values emptiness.

Answer (score 5):

```
if( myVariable ) 
{ 
    //mayVariable is not : 
    //null 
    //undefined 
    //NaN 
    //empty string ("") 
    //0 
    //false 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can play here with different types and check the output,

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/rgtu1TlJ5DGAEWYxk5f6?p=preview)

```
export class ParentCmp {
  myVar:stirng="micronyks";
  myVal:any;
  myArray:Array[]=[1,2,3];
  myArr:Array[];

    constructor() {
      if(this.myVar){
         console.log('has value')     // answer
      }
      else{
        console.log('no value');
      }

      if(this.myVal){
         console.log('has value') 
      }
      else{
        console.log('no value');      //answer
      }


       if(this.myArray){
          console.log('has value')    //answer
       }
       else{
          console.log('no value');
       }

       if(this.myArr){
             console.log('has value')
       }
       else{
             console.log('no value');  //answer
       }
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
user:Array[]=[1,2,3];
if(this.user.length)
{
    console.log("user has contents");
}
else{
    console.log("user is empty");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ar you looking for that:

```
isEmptyObject(obj) {
  return (obj && (Object.keys(obj).length === 0));
}
```

(found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37111836/1767316))

or that :

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

found [here](https://coderwall.com/p/_g3x9q/how-to-check-if-javascript-object-is-empty)

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you know the given variable **Type**. If you expect it to be an **Object** than you could check if myVar is an empty **Object** like this:

```
 public isEmpty(myVar): boolean {
     return (myVar && (Object.keys(myVar).length === 0));
 }
```

Otherwise: **if (!myVar) {}**, should do the job

Answer (score -1):

Angular 4 empty data if else

```
if(this.data == 0)
{
alert("Null data");
}
else
{
//some logic
}
```