# Can't check if array is initialized or empty with ngIf

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a property on my component for alert messages that may get populated:

```
alerts: ReportAlertMessage[];
```

I am trying to us `ngIf` to display an output if the array has any data.

I first tried:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="alerts">
```

But it didn't work, it returns this error:

> Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

So I tried:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="typeof(alerts) !== 'undefined'">
```

and this gives me:

> self.context.typeof is not a function

I want to check that it is initialized and has at least 1 value.  What is the way to do this with `ngIf`?

edit:

full exception message.  Problem seems to be ocurring because I am populating the array with an observable:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
    at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3561:33)
    at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:30581:16)
    at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:30646:16)
    at new ViewWrappedError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:61302:16)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83662:23)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83635:18)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:62229:20)
    at RouterOutlet.activate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:67737:42)
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25393:16)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25360:26)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25296:58
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25296:29)
    at ActivateRoutes.activate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25270:14)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:24830:22
```

I have also tried writing a static bool.  It appears that this error occurs when I set the value of a property inside the callback from an observable

Comment: `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined` this error seems be related to something else.. Are you using `ElementRef` anywhere?

Comment: Why don't you check length of array `*ngIf="alerts?.length > 0"`. The first condition will return false if it is not initalized. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543362/angular2-ngif-check-object-array-length-in-template) question

Comment: @suraj I am using `ElementRef` in a different module.  I have commented it out just to be safe but I still get this error.

Comment: can you add the template? the first condition seems fine

Comment: @Nishant123 that generates same error.  If I remove this if statement the app works perfectly.  i am doing ngIf on some static bool properties and it works fine, maybe because this is a custom type?

Comment: @suraj the template is just the row and a test message.  I have removed everything else.  ngif works fine on static bool but not my array of custom type

Comment: can you add the properties of ReportAlertMessage?

Comment: @suraj `alert` appears to be a reserved name.  I renamed it to `alertMessages` and now it works.

Comment: you could add your solution and mark it.. Will help others

Comment: @suraj actually this did not fix.  `*ngIf="!alertMessages"` works, but `*ngIf="alertMessages"` give the nativeElement error

Comment: you will need to put the template code.. full loop.. its not *ngIf syntax

Comment: @suraj there is no loop, im just outputting text string

Comment: It seems issue is that I am setting property inside an observable.  After observable sets property it becomes inacessible.

Comment: sry.. the entire block. also component code.. I dont have the full picture here  to tell :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can call a method in your component as

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="isEmpty(alerts)">
```

Component function

```
isEmpty(alerts){
    if(alerts===[]) {
         return true;
    } else {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the first is the correct way to do it. It the **alerts** access modifier public

Comment: public is not really necessary as long as they are class properties

Answer (score 0):

Try this

<`div class="row" *ngIf="alerts.length">`