# 'ngIf ' on negative statement not working properly

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

Good day,

I have an issue when trying to use the `ngIF` in Angular, specifically, when the values has to be negative...

for example

I have this HTML code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" *ngIf ="identity">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
        Inicio
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
        Timeline
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        User
      </a>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

Where "identity" stores the user data and a token when logged in and it works fine as screenshot below

[image]

however, when I use the `ngIf = "!identity"` in the next div so different icons will display at the top right corner when no user has logged in, nothing happens

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" *ngIf ="!identity">
    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['/login']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
        Login
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['/register']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        Register
      </a>
    </li>

   </ul>
```

As you can see here, no user data nor token has been generated but still the icons at the top right corner aren't showing up

[image]

I'd already tried to use the `ngIf` else statement using the `<ng-template #anExample>` and adding the second div in it and add it to the `*ngIf ="identity; else anExample"` but still it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What is the value of  `identity` when no user logged in?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi shoot!!! I forgot to include it in my question: here is the function getIdentity(){
  let identity = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity')||'{}');

  if(identity != "undefined"){
   this.identity = identity;
  }else{
   this.identity= null;
  }

  return this.identity;
 }

Comment: Low rep so I have to add answer instead of a comment but definitely checked that you are getting faked out by something. Take off the ngIf and make sure it displays (css / formatting issue), if it is in the dev tools elements but not showing you know it is something else.

Comment: Hi @Wild Bill well...funny thing.. when I use this *ngIf ="!identity == false" it shows both left and right icons so I'm struggling with the logic here because if the false statement denies the non existence of a value in identity, this means that identity should contain something right?  I'd tried in incognito in both firefox and chrome and the issue continues

Comment: You are returning/parsing '{}' and it should be an empty object in these cases so here are some checks for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111005/how-to-check-empty-object-in-angular-2-template-using-ngif

Comment: truthy/falsy link, see specifically {} is truthy: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Answer (score 1):

As you see in the second picture we still see the `Inicio , Timeline and User` which means `identity` has value because you assign it to `{}`.

The `identity` variable never be `undefined` because of `{}`. In other words if `identity` does not exists in `localStorege` you assign it with empty object.
This is your function and `else part` never executed.

```
function getIdentity() {
    let temp  = localStorage.getItem('identity');
    let identity = temp != null ? JSON.parse(temp) : null;
    
    if (identity != null) 
        this.identity = identity; //always this executed
    else 
        this.identity = null;//never executed
    return this.identity;
}
```

You have to change `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity')||'{}');` to `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity'));`.

Comment: Thanks @Alireza Ahmadi I was thinking the same but if I remove the brackets and try to compile the code I have this message ` Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'. 
38   let identity = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity'));` 
I tried to declare 'identity: String;' and initialize it in the constructor as 'this.identity = 'String';' but still it give me the same error. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Alireza, I think I figured out, I'll post it answering my own question

Comment: @secaidadevstudent I edit my code. Please check that

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution here, after searching for a solution, I found that this is a TS bug mentioned here [False error "Type 'null' is not assignable" for Typescript code #1818](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/1818)
 so basically we need to change the `tsconfig.json` and include under the `"compilerOptions"` the following

```
"strictNullChecks": false,
```

And that's it, now it's working fine...thank you all for the help

Comment: No man that is not good way. You don't need disable checking null

Comment: please check [this](https://www.tsmean.com/articles/learn-typescript/strict-null-checks-best-practice/) to understand drawbacks of `"strictNullChecks": false`

Comment: Thanks bro...so I change it to `true` and my code still works fine so, based on your knowledge..what could the the downside of setting this as false?

Comment: you'll get more safety on compile time and avoid some problem that can occur in your app

Comment: Thanks man for the help...I'm still learning so if I encounter other issue I'll post it so maybe I can get your help
Cheers!

Comment: Yes...it works like a charm right now...when no one is logged in, the correct icons display in the correct position and once I log in (and refresh the browser), the "Inicio", "Timeline" and "User" icons appear.. you have no idea how frustrated I was but you know.. beginners mistakes but your suggestion of removing the "{}" from `JSONparse()` helped me to understand the logic here. Thanks!