# Angular *ngIf check if object only contains null values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I can check if the object itself is `null` with `(myObj | keyvalue)?.length`. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56532650/13797956)

With JS I can check if the object contains only `null` values with `Object.values(myObj).some(x => x !== null)`.
But when I try to use this in the template I get `Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments`.

Is there a way to check if `myObj` only contains `null` values inside the template or should I use a function that does the work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you should create a `EveryPipe` for that.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'every' })
export class ContainsPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(input: any, value: any): boolean {
      return Object.values(input).every(x => x == value)
   }
}
```

used like following

```
<div *ngIf="(myObj | every:null)"> 
   ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all. The template parser can not assign values to variables. But you are assigning the values of `myObj` to a local variable `x` in order to verify if there are any values equal to `null`.

You will have to create a method on the component or use a pipe to achieve what you want. For example, with a function:

`.html`:

```
<div *ngIf="containsOnlyNullValues(myObj)">
  // content to be conditionally displayed goes here ...
</div>
```

`.ts`:

```
public containsOnlyNullValues(myObj: any) {
  return Object.values(myObj).some(x => x !== null);
}
```

Note that you can [store the value of a conditional result as a variable](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-a-conditional-result-in-a-variable) which can be used later on in the template. But that is the only exception to this rule.